# 2d picture of triangle (->face features) in a 3D world how to detect if it's the same triangle

Tags: algorithm, geometry, computer-vision

I have a triangle picture. having the 3 points of several triangles how can I know if this is the same triangle or not? (same equals -similar since they do not need to be in the same size but need to have same angels)

My original problem matching faces using the point of eyes edges mouth edges and nose edges.
I thought of things like ration, but any good ideas will help me!
thanks

Comment: Do you have access to the 3d structure? That is, actual points in 3d space? Or do you just have 2d projective projections of that 3d space?

Comment: I have only the 2D projective

Comment: Could you give an example of the input you have available, and the expected output?

Comment: @ iccthedral I know that, the problem is that when I have the 2D projective I cannot know the original - let's say front shot angels- real angels of 2D shape

Answer (score 2):

For each triangle in the 3D space, project its points onto the plane defined by its three corners, then compare that to the template image.

If you don't actually have access to the 3d points, but only projections of them (as if taken by a camera), then you can't actually solve this problem. Distortion will cause many triangles that are not actually similar to appear the same under this projection.

If you assume that all the points lie on a plane parallel to the projection plane (like if you take a straight-on picture of a wall), then the 3D aspect of this is irrelevant. Just do congruency checks like you would in 2D.

Comment: My original problem is for faces having point of eyes nose and mouth. even if not 100% I think there might be a way for indicating match or mismatch??

Answer (score 1):

As @Sancho said, a triangle cannot be solved in 3-space if you don't know what plane it lies in.  If however you know certain properties about your shape (as you said, a face), say, eyes are always X distance apart, then you can likely use certain metrics to determine it's orientation (if it's rotated into the plane, etc.)

Or say, if you know eyes are always the same size, you know it's rotated into the plane parallel with your camera if one eye is small that the other, and if you know distance between the eyes, you can derive the angle that it's rotated.

Comment: +1 Good ideas for determining the possible plane. I think the asker may have been planning on using the triangle as a geometry check for face detection. Your solution presupposes the detection is a face, then assigns a plane assuming that's the case, so it will reject less false positives than otherwise, but.. I don't know what "otherwise" would actually be, without access to more info about the scene.